# express-resource custom mapping

Tags: node.js, express

I can't find any decent documentation on this that contains any depth when requiring with app.resource.

The only information that I can find is creating the variable within the current file. [Here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource/blob/master/examples/user.js)

The current code that I have is below:

```
var favs = app.resource('favs', require('./modules/favs'));
favs.map('get', '/user', favs.buses);
```

However it comes back saying that it is undefined?

In the module favs I have.

```
exports.buses = function (req, res) {
    res.render('favs/buses', {
        title: 'Bus Stops'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error in `favs.js`: The last right bracket `)` is redundant.

Apart from that, you seem to conflate the actual module with the resource object you get back from `app.resource`. You want to pass a reference to the request handler you want to invoke when a visitor hits the path (in your case, `/favs/user`). So what you want is something like:

```
var favs = require('./modules/favs'),
    favsResource = app.resource('favs', favs);

favsResource.map('get', '/user', favs.buses);
```

If you feel a little lost dealing with `express-resource`, I encourage you to begin with plain express, and only start using express-resource when you are more familiar with how express works. TJ's helper modules have a tendency to be lacking in documentation, and you should use them only if you feel comfortable reading the code, IMO.

Comment: I see thank you for your help got it all working now :) thanks for your help and yeah the last bracket ) basically the above code I wrote for Stack Overflow. But thanks for your help :)